# How to add a tick mark to a slider if it cannot inherit QSlider

Tags: qt, qt4.7, qslider

I have a Qt dialog and there is a slider in it, when the dialog is initialized the slider will be set a value. In order to remind the user what is the default value, I want to add a mark to the slider, just draw a line or a triangle above the handle. Here, the slider should be of QSlider type, that means I can't implement a customized control derived from QSlider. Is there any way to realize it ?

Comment: You mean handle is positioned somewhere along slider range but you want to emphasize another position by drawing some kind of marker?

Comment: @Masci : I want to emphasize the default value of the slider, when user drags the handle, they can still see the original value of the slider since there is a mark for initial value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not clear why you can't derive a control from `QSlider`. You can still treat it like a `QSlider`, just override the `paintEvent` method. The example below is pretty cheesy, visually speaking, but you could use the methods from `QStyle` to make it look more natural:

```
#include <QtGui>

class DefaultValueSlider : public QSlider {
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  DefaultValueSlider(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent = NULL)
    : QSlider(orientation, parent),
      default_value_(-1) {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(VerifyDefaultValue(int)));
  }

 protected:
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *ev) {
    int position = QStyle::sliderPositionFromValue(minimum(),
                                                   maximum(),
                                                   default_value_,
                                                   width());
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.drawLine(position, 0, position, height());
    QSlider::paintEvent(ev);
  }

 private slots:
  void VerifyDefaultValue(int value){
    if (default_value_ == -1) {
      default_value_ = value;
      update();
    }
  }

 private:
  int default_value_;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  DefaultValueSlider *slider = new DefaultValueSlider(Qt::Horizontal);
  slider->setValue(30);

  QWidget *w = new QWidget;
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  layout->addWidget(slider);
  layout->addStretch(1);
  w->setLayout(layout);

  QMainWindow window;
  window.setCentralWidget(w);
  window.show();

  return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: thanks for mentioning `QStyle::sliderPositionFromValue`

Comment: Although `QStyle:: sliderPositionFromValue` does the math for us, it doesn't take into account the margin. The default tick drawing routines indent the first and last ticks. But sliderPositionFromValue does not, meaning that ticks drawn with drawLine at that position will not match the Slider position.

Comment: A quick fix is to use "width() - 20" for the tick position calculation, and add 10 to the returned position:  `int position = 10 + QStyle::sliderPositionFromValue(minimum(),
                                                   maximum(),
                                                   tickXPos,
                                                   width() - 20);`  Surely there is some way to get this margin from Qt, rather than hard-coding it?!!

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way I can think off is:

Add QSlider to QSlider (like you do it with layouts and QFrames). Slider above will be your current slider (clickable one). Slider below will be your "default tick position" value.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QSlider * defaultValueSlider = new QSlider();
    QSlider * valueSlider = new QSlider(defaultValueSlider);
    QVBoxLayout * lay = new QVBoxLayout(defaultValueSlider);
    lay->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    lay->setSpacing(0);
    lay->addWidget(valueSlider);
    defaultValueSlider->setRange(0, 100);
    valueSlider->setRange(0, 100);
    defaultValueSlider->setValue(30);

    defaultValueSlider->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to inherit a QSlider to access its public methods?

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qslider.html

You can just call its [setTickPosition()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qslider.html#tickPosition-prop) in your app.

Comment: sorry I didn't express my question clearly. I mean, for example, if the value of the slider is 30, there is only a mark at the position of 30.