# How to put ticks at custom places on a Qslider?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qslider

Hi I tried to implement a custom QSlider, but the ticks are always in intervalls, and i need to put them at specific places. I have no idea on how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

If you are just want to change the tick mark intervals, you can use [QSlider:setTickInterval()](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-maemo/qslider.html#tickInterval-prop).

From the documentation:

> tickInterval : int
>
> This property holds the interval between tickmarks.
>
> This is a value interval, not a pixel interval. If it is 0, the slider will choose between singleStep() and pageStep().
> The default value is 0.

If you want marks at non-regular intervals, you are going to need to override `paint()` ([see example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Cpp/Qt/SubclassQWidgettodopaint.htm)).

This is some untested example code:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QSlider::paintEvent(event);  // paints the slider like normal

    // Add your custom tick locations
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter.setPen(Qt::darkGreen);
    painter.drawRect(1, 2, 6, 4);    

    painter.setPen(Qt::darkGray);
    painter.drawLine(2, 8, 6, 2);
}
```

This probably contains a few errors, but it should illustrate the idea nicely.  You can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9802670/616644).  Good luck!